# PostgresOperator in Airflow getting error while passing parameter

Tags: postgresql, airflow

I have a dag which queries the postgress database, And I am using postgresOperator 
however when passing the parameter I am getting the below Error.

```
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: column "132" does not exist
LINE 1: ...d,derived_tstamp FROM atomic.events WHERE event_name = "132"
```

snapshot of my dag below :

```
default_args = {
            "owner": "airflow",
            "depends_on_past": False,
            "start_date": airflow.utils.dates.days_ago(1),
            "email": ["airflow@airflow.com"],
            "email_on_failure": False,
            "email_on_retry": False,
            "retries": 1,
            "retry_delay": timedelta(minutes=1),
            }


dag = DAG("PostgresTest", default_args=default_args, schedule_interval='3,33 * * * *',template_searchpath = ['/root/airflow/sql/'])

dailyOperator = PostgresOperator(
                    task_id='Refresh_DailyScore',
                    postgres_conn_id='postgress_sophi',
                    params={"e_name":'"132"'},
                    sql='atomTest.sql',
                    dag=dag)
```

Snapshot of atomTest.sql

```
SELECT domain_userid,derived_tstamp FROM atomic.events WHERE event_name = {{ params.e_name }}
```

I am hitting my head the whole day to understand why airflow is considering 132 values as column.

Please suggest.

Comment: can you try without `'` e.g. ` params={"e_name":"132"},`?

Comment: In postgres, string literals use single-quotes. Double-quotes are used to handle table/column/function/etc names that have unusual characters in them. I suspect that's your problem -- you're passing the string `"132"` to postgres, which sees it as a table or column name.